# Centered frame title in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, titles

How to set up `beamer` in a document so that frame titles are centered? Most of the themes seem to use left aligned frame titles.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365539/centering-titles-when-using-the-beamer-class-in-latex

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can control the title alignment by using the second optional argument of the `frametitle` template (See page 75 of the beamer documentation):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work well with some themes, like `Rochester`, which I use with the option `height=\baselineskip`. In this case the title frame height is completely ignored.

Comment: @Romildo: in this case, simply add `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace{-1.6\baselineskip}}`
to my solution.