# Need a centred headline in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a presentation to put together and I need to specify the classification of each page (UNCLASSIFED) centred at the very top (above the Frametitle) and at the very bottom. I tried using `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{UNCLASSIFIED}`, for example, but all it does is stick the classification on the far left. When I add it within `\begin{center}{}\end{center}`, nothing happens. In either case, I get nothing for the footline.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\section{Background:  The Problem}
\frame{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
\begin{center}
{\bf UNCLASSIFIED} 
\end{center}
}
\frametitle{Background:  The Problem}
\begin{itemize}
{\small
\item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff;
\item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff;
\item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff;
\item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff;
\item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff;
\item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff;}
\end{itemize}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\begin{center}{\bf UNCLASSIFIED}
\end{center}
}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a lot of stuff

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! I've cleaned up the formatting of your code. Use the 'edit' button to see what I've done. Never use `\bf` - it is deprecated 20 years ago! Use `\textbf{}` or `\bfseries` instead.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46987/centered-frame-title-in-beamer)

Comment: Try `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{{\makebox[\paperwidth][c]{\bfseries UNCLASSIFIED}}}`. Use `\bfseries` instead of `\bf` BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{headline}{class}[1]{%
    \vskip5pt%
    \makebox[\paperwidth][c]{\textbf{#1}}%
}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{class}[1]{%
    \vskip-3pt
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{\paperwidth}
        \centering
        \textbf{#1}\\
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

    \setbeamertemplate{headline}[class]{unclassified}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[class]{unclassified}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Background:  The Problem}
        test
    \end{frame}

    \setbeamertemplate{headline}[class]{classified}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[class]{classified}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Background:  The Problem}
        test
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]