# Beamer Slide Title Is Not Centered

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, presentations, frame-title, center

The photo below describes my question. I checked but could not find a duplicate question

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty  %no navigation pane
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\title[A Smaller Title]{Title for the Presentation}
\author[John Doe]{John Doe}

\institute[]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{image-placeholder.jpg}}
\date[{\includegraphics[height=2mm]{image-placeholder.jpg}}]{Some Day in 2021} 


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}



\section{some section}
\subsection{some subsection}
\begin{frame}{\centerline{A Long Title Here But Does Not Look Centered}}


I was wondering why the long title does not look centered, and what can I do to make it centered.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to horizontally center the frame titles of all your frames, add `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]` as for example described here: [How do I horizontally center the title in a slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329878/134144), here: [Beamer query, center justify \frametitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225061/134144) or here: [Centered frame title in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46987/134144)

Comment: This did not resolve my problem. After adding "\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]" to the preamble, I still face with the same exact problem. Is this an inherent problem of beamer, or maybe I am going over the line limit with the long frame title.

Comment: In addition to adding `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]` to the preamble of your document, also remove the `\centerline` command from the frametitle. Using `\begin{frame}{A Long Title Here But Does Not Look Centered}` should result in a horizontally centered frame title.

Comment: I see, ```\centerline``` seems to be the real culprit. Thanks, it works perfectly fine right now.